# Storing pdf as tmp and pointing webbrowser to it

Tags: pdf, io, webbrowser-control, .net

I am a bit confused as to how I point my webbrowser to a temporary PDF file.. If I point it to the PDF, I get a download box dialog asking me to download a file and invalid browser page.

```
WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
DocumentContainer.Child = b;
temporaryFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(temporaryFileName, this.CurrentDocument.DocumentData); //pdf
b.Navigate(temporaryFileName);
```

I also tried to write my file to Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData for the hell of it and am getting hit with an error

```
"file does not begin with '%pdf'"

WebBrowser b = new WebBrowser();
DocumentContainer.Child = b;
temporaryFileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + this.CurrentDocument.Title+".pdf";
System.IO.File.Create(temporaryFileName);//pdf
b.Navigate(temporaryFileName);
```

I've done this several times with other files but for somereason it does not want to work with pdf!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
b.Navigate("file://" + temporaryFileName);
```

Comment: @Adrian What happened exactly?

Comment: The same exact thing that was happening before. I get _Navigation to web page was cancelled_ as well as a download dialog asking me to download a .tmp

Comment: Did you first make sure your code works ok with a non-temp PDF?